# Unix - List all files in all directories without displaying full path?

Tags: file, unix, find, subdirectory

Is this possible?

```
find /home/me/subdir -type f
```

The code above is alright, but I dont want it to display the full path and hidden files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
find /home/me/subdir -type f ! -name ".*" -exec basename {} \;
```

Or your `find` may allow this:

```
find /home/me/subdir -type f ! -name ".*" -printf "%f\n"
```

**ADDED AFTERWARDS**

To list the largest files, you first need to find their size, maybe like this:

```
stat --printf "%n:%s\n" somefilename
```

where `%n` is the size and `%s` is the name.

Then if you want the sizes of **all** files, you need to run `find`:

```
find /home/me/subdir -type f -exec stat --printf "%n:%s\n" {} \;
```

Then if you want them sorted, and the 10 biggest, you need to add `sort` and `head`:

```
find /home/me/subdir -type f -exec stat --printf "%n:%s\n" {} \; | sort -rn | head -n 10
```

Comment: What OS are you on? Mac OSX? Ubuntu?

Comment: Have another look - I am guessing Ubuntu-isms as I run on Mac OSX.